# Ставит ли компилятор неявные фигурные скобки в if()?

Tags: c++

Подставляет ли компилятор неявно фигурные скобки в:

```
if(true)
   int a = 1;
```

Ибо если мы позже попытаемся вывести значение переменной а, то мы этого сделать не сможем. Складывается такое впечатление, что там стоят фигурные скобки которые ограничивают область видимости этой переменной

Comment: Так и без явных скобок у `int a = 1;` ограничена область видимости из-за `if(true)`

Comment: если не ставить скобки, то будет выполняться только одна операция

Comment: можно считать, что там есть неявные скобки. Если бы область видимости ограничивал именно if, тогда следующий код компилировался бы `int main()
{
    if (true)
        int a = 1;
    else
        a = 2;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Возьмём подробнее пространства переменных для команды `if` :

```
{ int a = 1 ;
  int b = 0 ;
  if ( int a = 2 ) {
    int b = a + 1 ; }
  else {
    int b = a - 1 ; } }
```

Область действия переменной `a` в условии создаётся новой. И похожа на такое :

```
{ int a = 1 ;
  int b = 0 ;
  // область действия второй переменой a
  { int a = 2 ;
    if ( a ) {
      int b = a + 1 ; } // a == 2 , b == 3
    else {
      int b = a - 1 ; } } // a == 2 , b == 1
  // область действия второй переменой a 
  }
```

Единственная проблема это дествие переменной `a` в условии. Область её действия работает как в успешном условии так и в отрицательном. И вторую копию переменной `a` определить нельзя.

```
{ int a = 1 ;
  int b = 0 ;
  if ( int a = 2 ) {
    int a ; // error : redeclaration
    int b = a + 1 ; }
  else {
    int a ; // error : redeclaration
    int b = a - 1 ; } }
```

При объявлении переменной при каком-то условии эта переменная имеет область действия только в данном участке.

```
{ int a = 1 ;
  int b = 0 ;
  // b == 0
  if ( int a = 2 ) {
    int b = a + 1 ; } // b == 3
  else {
    int b = a - 1 ; } // b == 1
  // b == 0
  }
```

Переменные `b` все три разные, и так как объявление переменной это одно выражение, то фигурные скобки можно опускать. Действие будет аналогиное. Будут три разных переменных `b`.

```
{ int a = 1 ;
  int b = 0 ;
  // b == 0
  if ( int a = 2 ) 
    int b = a + 1 ;  // b == 3
  else 
    int b = a - 1 ;  // b == 1
  // b == 0
  }
```

Взято из https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Notes

---

ответ :

Видимости переменной, объявленной в успешной ветке не будет в негативной ветке, так как не будет вызван конструктор этой переменной.

Видимости переменной, объявленной в успешной ветке не будет после окончании конструкции `if`, так-как при негативном условии не будет вызван конструктор.

Из-за чёткого правила, что переменная должна быть с вызванным конструктором и деструктором вытекает такой порядок их вызовов :

```
{ int a = 1 ; конструктор a I
  int b = 0 ; конструктор b I
  { int a = 2 ; конструктор a II
    if ( a ) {
      int b = a + 1 ; конструктор b II
      деструктор b II          
      }
    else {
      int b = a - 1 ; конструктор b III
      деструктор b III          
      } 
    деструктор a II
    }
  деструктор b I
  деструктор a I
  }
```

Условного объявления переменной `a` нет.

```
if(true)
  int a = 1;
```

Она будет однозначно объявлена **только** при выполнении условия **true** и **обязательно** будет вызван деструктор в конце **этой** ветки условия.